# Mark a location on a map (Google Maps/OpenLayers) on a node creation or edit page - but with which module?

Tags: google-maps, javascript, entities, location

I have a custom content type, and I would like my users to **mark a location on a Google Maps/OpenLayers map, save these coordinates**, and on the frontend, show the location's map and the GPS coordinates.

So the user has the opportunity to just simply click on the map somewhere, and mark a location. BUT if the user wants to, he/she can also type an address, and geocode it.
([In this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/14659/2368), the OP just wants the latter opportunity.)

I would also like to have a page where the different locations are listed, which are related to the given nodes. Plus maybe some search opportunities.

Geolocation Field seems correct, but I'm a bit confused whether the other modules are better for this task, or what's the difference between them.

The possible modules:

- [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield),
- [GMap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) (unfortunately stating *"GMap is considered a legacy module."*)
- [Geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/geocoder),
- [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
- [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
- [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
- [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location),
- [OpenLayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers/),
- [OpenLayers Locator](http://drupal.org/project/ol_locator) (that's a *buggy* feature as an own experience),
- etc...

---

(For example, Get Locations looks promising because of the many opportunities. But OpenLayers too... Geolocation Field seems like a little simpler, but also with less opportunities (concentrating on just marking a place on the map). By the way, I don't really understand Get Locations field's module page, firstly it states that it has *"Support for Geolocation (Drupal 7)"*, but later there's the following sentence: *"Please note* - *Do not install the `Location` module or the `Geofield`, `Addressfield` or `Geolocation` modules at the same time as `Getlocations_fields`, this will not work."*)

Comment: [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield), [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield), and [Geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/geocoder) would be the best combination with [OpenLayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers).

Comment: OK, thanks, but why is it better than for example [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations) module, which has many opportunities too? I would like to compare these modules to be able to select the "best" possible.

Answer (score 3):

I had a good experience with [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation).

I used this module on dealing website to show location of store. It lets you mark location via node creation/edition form and have display formatter to rendering the address as PNG or Google map.

It was simple and good enough.

Comment: hi what display formatter did you use?

Comment: +1, thanks, and sorry for the late feedback. Do you know what's the real difference between [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation) you are recommending and [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations) module? On the Get Locations' module page, firstly it writes it supports Geolocation Field, but after that there is a note that _"Do not install the Location module or the Geofield, Addressfield or **Geolocation** modules at the same time as Getlocations_fields, this will not work."_ GetLocations also has a field that can be added, this all makes me really confused.