# How to output Get Locations coordinates as a separate field?

Tags: 7, google-maps, location

I have [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations) module enabled, and I would like to **output the coordinates of a given location as a separate field** (longitude, latitude) **when displaying a given node**.

Somehow like this:
**GPS**: 45° 59' 45.24" N, 18° 40' 47.28" E

What's the best solution to do this?
Should I use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) + "Add a code field" or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it with creating a custom Display Suite field, which can be dragged on the admin interface similar to "regular" fields.
I can suggest this article for quick understanding: http://previousnext.com.au/blog/creating-custom-display-suite-fields-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-use-hookdsfieldsinfo

To get the necessary data from the field, I used [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) like this article suggests (this is a must-read!): http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

This is how I created my custom Display Suite field for getting GPS data from the [Get Locations](https://drupal.org/project/getlocations) field:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ds_fields_info().
 * @see http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ds!ds.api.php/function/hook_ds_fields_info/7
 */
function TESTMODULE_ds_fields_info($entity_type) {
  $fields = array();

  $fields['node']['MYNODETYPE_gps'] = array(
    // title: title of the field
    'title' => t('GPS'),
    // type: type of field
    // - DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION   : calls a custom function.
    'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
    // ui_limit : only used for the manage display screen so
    // you can limit fields to show based on bundles or view modes
    // the values are always in the form of $bundle|$view_mode
    // You may use * to select all.
    // Make sure you use the machine name.
    'ui_limit' => array('MYNODETYPE|*'),
    // function: only for DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION.
    'function' => 'TESTMODULE_MYNODETYPE_ds_field_gps',
  );

  if (isset($fields[$entity_type])) {
    return array($entity_type => $fields[$entity_type]);
  }
  return array();
}

/**
 * Generate GPS coordinates as a DS field
 * Example: 46° 2' 27.24" N 18° 40' 37.2" E
 */
function TESTMODULE_MYNODETYPE_ds_field_gps($field, $title = NULL){
  $output = '';

  // http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way
  // instead of the ugly $on_the_map_getlocations_field_data = $field['entity']->field_MYNODETYPE_on_the_map['und'][0];
  $on_the_map_getlocations_field = field_get_items('node', $field['entity'], 'field_MYNODETYPE_on_the_map');

  if(isset($on_the_map_getlocations_field[0])){    
    $on_the_map_getlocations_field_data = $on_the_map_getlocations_field[0];

    if(isset($on_the_map_getlocations_field_data['latitude']) && isset($on_the_map_getlocations_field_data['latitude'])){
      $output .= theme('getlocations_latitude_dms', $on_the_map_getlocations_field_data);
      $output .=  ' ';
      $output .= theme('getlocations_longitude_dms', $on_the_map_getlocations_field_data);
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [geofield module](http://drupal.org/project/geofield). Even the Get Locations module supports it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why should I install it beyond having Get Locations module enabled? Get Locations stores lat/lon data, I just would like to "extract" that, and output it as a separate field. Isn't it an "overkill" to enable another module for that? BTW, do you think Geofield module has any advantages over Get Locations? Feel free to comment it here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39735/mark-a-location-on-a-map-google-maps-openlayers-on-a-node-creation-or-edit-pag, it would be great to read a little comparison regarding these modules. Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Get Geolocations seems to have support for Views.

If you add a view can't you add a field with the geolocation info and display them as lat/lon?

Comment: yes, but as I wrote, I have to display this information **when displaying a given node**, so in the regular node display mode, as a separate field with label, not in a view.

Comment: You could make a template for the node, or the field, and there, via php, get lat/lon, or include the view

Comment: I was thinking about implementing `hook_entity_view_alter()` or another hook to make it look nice and easily modifiable, but I don't know what would be the nice solution for that - that's why I'm asking. :)

Comment: I think that a good solution is to add a tpl for the field.