# Show Distance in table from openlayers

Tags: 7, javascript, location

So I followed the instructions from this thread; [Need a simple Google Maps solution; lost in the labyrinth of modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/need-a-simple-google-maps-solution-lost-in-the-labyrinth-of-modules). I've gotten everything to work how I need it on my test server a few months ago. The SS below shows how it looks with the distance/proximity working. 
[image]

Just before I got it working. I had a problem that the distance would not show based off the address or zip searched for. After some tinkering with views (atleast I think it was views), I finally got the distance working.

Now, my boss wants me to push it live and I can't remember how I got the distance to calculate based off an address or zipcode when I expose the proximity in views. It looks like the following;

[image]

I've opened both my test server and live side by side and checked over tons of the settings MANY MANY times over and still haven't been able to figure out what I missed. I've tried the following;

- Refreshing the Proximity calculations via the openlayers/proximity tab
- Tinkering with many different views settings.
- Creating new test nodes
- Rebuilding the process from the beginning

If you guys can maybe point me in the right direction or just mention SOMETHING that maybe I haven't thought about it would be great help. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got this sorted yet?

Ensure that you're using the "Geofield - proximity" field for output and not the Proximity - distance field. I've tried using the latter and not had it working (yet).