# Display distance Coordinate vs Zip Code?

Tags: views

I am trying display Coordinate vs Zip distance. User inputs zip they get a list of things close. Trying to work with Openlayers and expand on this post.
[Need a simple Google Maps solution; lost in the labyrinth of modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/need-a-simple-google-maps-solution-lost-in-the-labyrinth-of-modules)

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxeskzN8BAc) helped me when i set my first proximity search.

It goes through eveything you need, and once done, is easily configurable.

Comment: Hi Collins :-). Can I do that Coordinates vs Zip Code with this? Stored node has coordinates, exposed filter has Zip input. Thanks!

Comment: oops.. I will watch that video too (missed the link), but I have done a basic proximity search before.

Comment: Yep, the first few values of a zip code or post code are stored in the database alongside their relevant lat and long values, so the users Inputted postcode can be searched by lthe nodes lat long.

Comment: Well, the tutorial is something I had already done in Drupal 6, so I think I need to tweak some more. I am looking for exposed text field (no operator for math) to enter zip code. My admin has coordinates so I don't want a zip along side the coordinate in the node. The search would actually take zip input from anonymous user, calculate it's coordinate and compare it to node coordinate then return a summary list of closest to zip first. Thanks for the help.